# data from every table with a given name matching string

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

In my database are many tables with similar names;  abc-123, abc-245, abc-246, etc.
Each of these tables have a date field with each record, called sampledate.  I would like to find the oldest record in each table with a name that matches 'abc-%'.  I can get them individually, but there must be an easy way to select the data from a set of tables!

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a UNION query.  A UNION combines the results of two or more queries into a single result set that includes all the rows that belong to all queries in the union. The UNION operation is different from using joins that combine columns from two tables.

Example:

```
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM Production.ProductModel
WHERE ProductModelID NOT IN (3, 4)
UNION
SELECT ProductModelID, Name
FROM dbo.Gloves
ORDER BY Name
```

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180026.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is write a query that writes a query (aka "Code that writes code").  For instance, this initial query should generate a tsql statement that will give you the final data you are looking for.
Tweak the WHERE clause as needed:

```
SELECT 'SELECT ''[' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.TABLE_NAME + ']'' AS TableName, MAX(SampleDate) AS MaxDate FROM [' + c.TABLE_SCHEMA + '].[' + c.TABLE_NAME + '] UNION ALL'
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c
WHERE c.TABLE_NAME LIKE 'ABC-%'
AND c.COLUMN_NAME = 'SampleDate'
```

If you are in SSMS, it's a little easier if you set the output to text (CTRL + T).  After you run the query, you'll see something similar to this in the output window:

```
SELECT '[dbo].[ABC-123]' AS TableName, MAX(SampleDate) AS MaxDate FROM [dbo].[ABC-123] UNION ALL
SELECT '[dbo].[ABC-456]' AS TableName, MAX(SampleDate) AS MaxDate FROM [dbo].[ABC-456] UNION ALL
SELECT '[dbo].[ABC-78]' AS TableName, MAX(SampleDate) AS MaxDate FROM [dbo].[ABC-78] UNION ALL
SELECT '[dbo].[ABC-90]' AS TableName, MAX(SampleDate) AS MaxDate FROM [dbo].[ABC-90] UNION ALL
```

Copy & paste the output into a new window.  Remove "UNION ALL" from the last line, then run the query.

Comment: Edited answer to only include tables that contain a column named 'SampleDate'